# Android pick a Folder to scan for files (File manager Intent)

Tags: android

I have a list of pdfs within folders. 
I'd like to show the file manager to select a Folder (not a pdf). 
The application will then scan the selected folder and list the pdfs.

Is this possible by File Manager Intent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no file manager in Android. Third-party file managers may or may not offer some sort of folder-selecting `Intent` action.

I would recommend that you implement this UI in your application directly. A search on `android pick folder` turns up a few candidate libraries and code samples, such as [this blog post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/547636/Android-Ready-to-use-simple-directory-chooser-dial) and [this open source project](https://github.com/passy/Android-DirectoryChooser).